# Error on compile tibia source

Tags: compilation, cmake

I'm trying compile tibia server with CMake 3.1.3 but I'm getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1182 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.57.0

  Boost include path: C:/Users/maria de lourdes/Downloads/boost_1_57_0

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_thread

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGMP.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "GMP", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GMP" with any of
  the following names:

    GMPConfig.cmake
    gmp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "GMP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "GMP_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "GMP" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Tibia/src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: The error is not during compilation, its during configuration where all dependencies are figured out. It complaints that it cannot find Boost threads. Have you compiled Boost? Additionally it complains that GMP is not installed, you have to download and maybe compile this library.

Comment: omg. i've to compile it? really ? how can i do that?

Comment: It depends, have you downloaded the pre-build package or just the sources? With the pre-build it should just work. Then you have to add the path to the boost library in `BOOST_ROOT`, cf. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: thanks @usr1234567